# call a function in background in c++ similar to unix shell scripting

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, visual-c++, unix

I want to call function in parallel in c++ the function will take input and perform some formatting, validations , enhancements etc etc .

In unix I can call it inside a loop and pass the values as arguments with function running in BG &.

Example in shell script is :

```
echo $value | while read arg1 arg2
do
     parser arg1 arg2 &
done
wait
```

How to do it in c++ with/without multi threading ?

Thanks...

Comment: If you're not executing in a multi-threaded environment chances are what you ask is not easily attainable. My advice is to learn about threading.

Comment: You list both visual-c++ and unix. Are you looking for a good solution that is portable to both windows and unix, or an ideal solution one one of the two?

Comment: Runs on both Unix and Windows, my c++ pogram has to get some data from a unix env and performs certain actions . Currently I dont have privileges to access compiler on unix env. I have raised a request but not sure about the time it will take.

Comment: Multiple *processes* are launched with `fork` and `exec` in Posix; multiple *threads* are handles with pthreads.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Can you plz point me to a c/c++ example where a similar thing is done . Calling a function using fork multiple number of time, similar to what I did in the script above. Could not get past of parent and child concept, when I compare it to the script above.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run things 'in the background' or 'in parallel', you must use multithreading (either use multiple threads in the same process, or use multiple processes, depending on the specific case). Whenever you want to run something in the background, you should create a new thread/process, and tell it to run the code you want running in the background, and keep on doing the rest of your code in the original thread/process.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you'll have to either create a sub-process or a thread. Both of these techniques require system dependent code. If you want to be system-independent and have access to a compiler supporting it (I'm not aware of any compiler that doesn't), you can use [OpenMP](http://openmp.org) to do the multi-threading. However, this technique is mostly suited to problems where all the threads perform the same action.